# Silverstripe 3: removeByName not working

Tags: field, silverstripe, data-objects

Good morning,

I've been trying to use the removeByName method and it doesn't work.
I'm basically trying to hide a field in my DataObject within the forms that's generated by ModelAdmin, which manages the object.

See sample code below:

```
///DataObject snippet...
class MyObject extends DataObject{
   public static $db = array(
       'Title' => 'Varchar',
       'Desc' => 'Text',
       'Template' => 'HTMLText',
   );

   //@Override
   public function getCMSField(){
       $fields = parent::getCMSField();
       $fields->removeByName('Template'); /// DOESN'T WORK!!!
       return $fields;
   }

}//class
```

Note: I'm not getting any errors. I'm just still seeing the field on the forms (Add and Edit) as usual.

Any help appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Did you tryed naming the field in a different manner, like for example 'TemplateTest'?

Comment: Nope, I didn't initially. I've just tried it, and it still doesn't work. It's still showing in the form just with the title 'Template Test'. Thanks for the effort though, any other ideas are more than welcomed.

Comment: If someone can tell/show me how to debug the function 'getCMSField', like doing a var_dump on the $fields variable that would be helpful as well. Thanks. I've tried: Debug::show($fields) [don't work] even with the url query string [?debug=1&isDev=1] appended. I've even tried die(var_dump($fields)), and I get nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I found the issue.

I was just going over the API again for the millionth time, and recognized that I've named the function wrong. See correction below:

```
///Correction, forgot to add the 's' at the end of both the function and the parent call.
public function getCMSFields(){
    $fields = parent::getCMSFields();
}
```

I can understand an error not being generated in Apache logs for the function because it's legit. But as for the parent call, it should of generated an error since the method don't exists. (Theory: Perhaps, since the function was never actually being called, the parent call wasn't being executed and thus no errors [run-time error]).

Comment: right, your function `getCMSField()` (without s) was never called by SilverStripe

Comment: Thanks for verifying.